# In python how to return one list containing many lists

Tags: python

read_input(fileName):

This function is to take one argument which will be the name of a CSV file with the data values we wish to process.

This function is to read the CSV file, assuming the column input format is [species, Individual ID, allele (A or B), gene sequence, beak shape score (i.e., the degree of pointedness), beak type] and creating a list variable for each individual of length 7 with the format [species, Individual ID, alleleA gene, alleleB gene, alleleA beak shape score, alleleB beak shape score, beak type]. Your function should return one list, which is the list of all those lists. Use this list of the data as the finches list for the subsequent functions.

The data is the CSV file is guaranteed to always have two lines of data for each Individual ID. One line will be for the individual with the allele A gene of ALX1. The second line will be for the individual with the allele B gene of ALX1. These two line will always be consecutive in the CSV file with the allele A line occurring immediately before the allele B line. The two lines of data from the for the Individual ID are to be merged into a single list item for the list being returned by the function. Note that first line ("the A line") for an Individual ID from the CSV file will give information from positions 0, 1, 3, 4 and 5 in the list read from the CSV file. These five values will be stored into positions 0, 1, 2, 4, and 6 in the newly created list for each individual. The second line ("the B line") for an Individual ID from the CSV file will give information from positions 3 and 4 in the list read from the CSV file. These two values will be stored into position 3 and 5 in the newly created list for each individual. Below is the code but getting errors as my finches is only one list containing many string, but it should be one list containing many lists. how can I achieve that.
def read_input(fileName):

```
import csv
# open file as usual and read
fileref = open("finches.csv", "r")
# reading file. also created csv reader object from the fileref
data_reader = csv.reader(fileref)
#creating empty list called rows
row = []

for i in data_reader:
  if(i[2] == 'A'):
      x = i
      del x[2]
  else:
      x.insert(3, i[3])
      x.insert(4, i[5])
      row.append(x)
      
# close the file
fileref.close()

return row
pass
```

Comment: Welcome to SO fahim. Your question is very lengthy and unclear, consider being more concise. It would also be great if you could provide with a minimal working example, so that we can understand what your input is, and with an example of what kind of output you want.

Comment: It will be better if you can give a sample input, output with current code, and expected output. Besides, is this really your working code? It should raise error as `x` doesn't exist in else statement, and it should not return string when `x` is a list.

Answer (score -1):

You are using `return` that only works inside a function:

```
import csv

def read_input(fileName):
  with open(fileName, 'r') as fileref:
      data_reader = csv.reader(fileref)
      row = []
    
      for i in data_reader:
        if(i[2] == 'A'):
            x = I
            del x[2]
        else:
            x.insert(3, i[3])
            x.insert(4, i[5])
            row.append(x)

  return row
```

Comment: hey its not working. giving error The function 'read_input' returned a sub-list of an incorrect length.

Comment: Maybe consider using `with open(fileName, 'r') as fileref` instead of `open()` and `close()`. And I'm not sure you are answering the question. This would maybe be better as a comment.